# Insert NULL value into SQL Server from Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am trying to do a simple insert or update into SQL Server as NULL, not blank. I have seen many references online to just set Field = NULL without quotes but it is still coming up as empty, not NULL. Incredibly frustrating.

This is in classic asp.

```
If Request.Form("Field") = "" or IsNull(Request.Form("Field")) then
    Field = NULL
Else
    Field = Request.Form("Field")
End If

sSql="UPDATE [table] SET timestamp = {fn NOW()}," &_ 
    "Field = '" & Field & "'," &_
    "WHERE [System] = '" & System & "' and Active = '1'"
```

If I do this, it proves that it is checking because it puts in a 1.

```
If Request.Form("Field") = "" or IsNull(Request.Form("Field")) then
    Field = 1
Else
    Field = Request.Form("Field")
End If

sSql="UPDATE [table] SET timestamp = {fn NOW()}," &_ 
"Field = '" & Field & "'," &_
"WHERE [System] = '" & System & "' and Active = '1'"
```

I tried this but get an error 500:

```
    sSql="UPDATE [Table] SET timestamp = {fn NOW()}, Field = "
If IsNull(Field) Then
    sSQL = sSQL & "NULL"
Else
    sSQL = sSQL & "'" & Field & "'" &_
End If
"NTLogon = '" & UCase(NTLogon) & "'" &_
"WHERE [System] = '" & System & "' and Active = '1'"
```

When I try this in place of my original code:
Field Assignment:

```
Field = "NULL" and Field = "'" & Request.Form("Field") & "'"
```

sSQL:

```
"Field = " & Field & "," &_
```

I get "An error occurred on the server when processing the URL."

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is a textbook example of sql injection.

Comment: make sure your table does not have a default value of empty for that column.. then just set `Field = "NULL"` and `Field = "'" & Request.Form("Field") & "'"`   and change sql to `"Field = " & Field & "," &_`  then realize you should be using parameterized queries and change it all again

Answer (score 2):

So yeah, insert rant here about using parameterized queries, blah blah blah... now that's out of everyone's system, could we maybe look at the actual question?

The problem is this:

```
"Field = '" & Field & "'"
```

Those ampersands are converting your lovingly-populated vbScript `NULL` value right back into a string. If you don't want that to happen, you need to explicitly handle the `IsNull` case.

```
sSQL = "UPDATE [table] SET timestamp = {fn NOW()}, Field = "
If IsNull(Field) Then
    sSQL = sSQL & "NULL"
Else
    sSQL = sSQL & "'" & Field & "'"
End If
sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE [System] = '" & System & "' AND Active = '1'"
```

Note that even if you do this via a parameterized query, you'll need to make sure you're not appending your vbScript `NULL` value onto a string, because `"" & NULL = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

@pinchetpooche Hello there.  I had the same issue and tried the given answer, and also received a 500 error page.  I found that @Martha forgot to include the necessary SQL field that is being updated (i.e., "Field").  So I put together some test code, using her solution (i.e., using string concatenation and conditional logic), and executed against an actual database, and this solution works perfectly:

```
sSQLNullTest = "UPDATE CustomersToCCData SET " 
sSQLNullTest = sSQLNullTest & "CustomerID = " & iCustomerID & ", "
                    
   If IsNull(x_license_number_state) Or x_license_number_state = "" Then

     sSQLNullTest = sSQLNullTest & "CCLicenseState = NULL"

   Else
   
     sSQLNullTest = sSQLNullTest & "CCLicenseState = '" & x_license_number_state & "' "
   
   End If
                    
sSQLNullTest = sSQLNullTest & " WHERE CCID = '" & iCCInfoCCID & "'
```